# Stack trace issues on GDB

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am using GDB in remote configuration. So I have gdbserver running on a ARM HW running linux,  I connect to remote gdbserver from local gdb, I am able to put breakpoints in initial part of code and ensure that basically GDB works. However when I let my SW run for a while and break to see threads, I don't get useful stack traces for threads. All stack frames are hex addressed none resolving to symbols present in my binaries. Most of them also look the same with gdb also hinting with "same stack frames, corrupted stack ??"

Since SW runs fine with or without debugger I don't doubt my SW. Anybody seen this issue or any idea what might be going on here.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you tell us exactly how you ran the debuggers, how you compiled your code, and a sample of the output you see.

Comment: Can you  manually resolve the addresses, ie determine that they actually *are* in your binary?  You can figure out what file is loaded where from the process's map tables in /proc and you can figure out the addresses of symbols within the mapping using objdump on your unstripped binary.  Does your gdb have a host-side copy of unstripped binaries to reference?

Comment: @xaxxon, I will add more detail, thanks for reply

Comment: @Chris, At host side I have copy of unstripped binaries. Sometimes stack of some thread does resolve to a symbol name. To resolve manually I need base address (so I can get offset), I don't have access to /proc as it is proprietary linux HW. Is there way to know base address from GDB ?

Comment: You seem to be able to execute custom code on the box, so what do you mean you do not have access to /proc?  Is there literally no /proc filesystem?  Any way, you can also just have your program generate debug output of the actual addresses of a few functions from whatever files are of interest, and use that to figure out the base address of the section of the binary containing them.